# How to return the modified date for specific file types within a path in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a file path that I need to return the list of file names in it + the last modified date each file in Python. I am able to do this except the problem is that I only want to do this for PDFs and there are multiples file types within the folder I'm working with. I have gotten to the point where I can get the file name and the modified date but run into an error when I try to put in the PDF only stipulation.

The below is what I have so far:

```
path = <insert path>

def ts_to_dt(ts):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)

for file in os.scandir(path):
    #if file.endswith(".pdf"):
     print(file.name, ts_to_dt(file.stat().st_atime))
```

When I try to execute with the line that is commented out (if file.endswith(".pdf")), I get this error:

```
if file.endswith(".pdf"):
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'nt.DirEntry' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

I'm new to Python so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) returns an iterator of [`os.DirEntry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) objects as you can see from the error message.

`os.DirEntry` have different properties that you can get, including a `name` property which is a String.

So you could do:

```
if file.name.endswith(".pdf"):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for this instead.

You can do something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

def print_access_times(path):
    path = Path(path)  # If path was either a str or Path object, this will work
    for file in path.iterdir():
        if file.suffix == '.pdf':
            print(file.name, ts_to_dt(file.stat().st_atime))
```

The problem with your code was that `os.scandir` yields [DirEntry](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) objects (which don't have a `endswith` method), not strings.  The `Path` objects from `pathlib` provide a more consistent interface for working with paths in Python.

You could have used `file.name.endswith('.pdf')` with the `os.scandir` solution instead.

To convert a Path object back into a string, you would use `file.as_posix()` or `str(file)`.

If you're not sure ahead of time whether the given path is a directory or not, then you can use the following to gracefully handle the error that would be raised:

```
def print_access_times(path):
    path = Path(path)  # If path was either a str or Path object, this will work
    try:
        for file in path.iterdir():
            if file.suffix == '.pdf':
                print(file.name, ts_to_dt(file.stat().st_atime))
    except NotADirectoryError:
        pass
```